# Binary Search Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search

In computer science, binary search, also known as half-interval search or logarithmic search, is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a sorted array.

The code returns true if an element is present in the array else returns false.

Any suggestion in improving the code is welcome.

**Binary_Search.h**

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_H
#define BINARY_SEARCH_H

bool binary_search(int ar[], int low, int high, int key);

#endif // BINARY_SEARCH_H
```

**Binary_Search.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Binary_Search.h"

/* search a key in an array using binary search */
bool binary_search(int ar[], int low, int high, int key)
{
  int mid;

  while ( low <= high )
    {
      // find the middle index
      mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);

      if ( ar[mid] == key ) // key found
        {
          return true;
        }
      else if ( ar[mid] > key ) // key may be on the left half
        {
          high = mid - 1;
        }
      else if ( ar[mid] < key ) // key may be on the right half
        {
          low = mid + 1;
        }
    }

  // key not found
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  int ar[] = {1, 7, 9, 10, 28, 28, 36, 49, 68, 99};

  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]); ++i )
    {
      if ( binary_search(ar, 0, sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]) - 1, ar[i]) )
        {
          std::cout << ar[i] << " is present" << std::endl;
        }
      else
        {
          std::cout << ar[i] << " is not present" << std::endl;
        }
    }

  int ar1[] = {-1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 50, 90, 98, 100};
  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(ar1) / sizeof(ar1[0]); ++i )
    {
      if ( binary_search(ar, 0, sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]) - 1, ar1[i]) )
        {
          std::cout << ar1[i] << " is present" << std::endl;
        }
      else
        {
          std::cout << ar1[i] << " is not present" << std::endl;
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your formatting style looks weird and unusual. But that's actually not a point for code review, unless there are certain style guides set up.

Comment: Well if you are pointing to the braces then `emacs` gives that kind of formatting. I don't know whether that is good or not

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the brace indentation. IIRC you can choose/edit the templates `emacs` applies.

Comment: I'll search that, but why the default indentation behavior is strange.

Comment: The more usual style is that the opening brace is at the same indentation level as the conditional/loop condition statement, or starts with one blank offset after that statement, and the closing brace is always at the  same indentation level as the conditional/loop condition statement.

Comment: [First hit on Google](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC). Learn to use your editor. Then, consider learning to use your standard library—the algorithm header includes `std::binary_search`.

Comment: I know there is a function in the standard library, but I wanted to write clean code on my own for learning.

Comment: Since Emacs is a GNU project, it's most likely it tries to enforce the GNU coding styles by default. The indentation style used by the GNU project is not universally liked (some might even say universally not liked outside of GNU).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Interface

Passing an array and then two indexes is a very C style of interface. In C++ it is much more common to pass two iterators. An iterator is a generalized form of pointer.

So rather than:

```
bool binary_search(int ar[], int low, int high, int key);
```

I would use:

```
template<typename I>
bool binary_search(I low, I high, int key);
```

Also rather than pointing at the first and last elements iterator ranges use a first and one past the last. This makes calculating sizes easier.

#### Code Review

Don't use `>> 1` to represent a divide by 2. The point of high level code is to write it so that it is easy for humans to read. That is not obvious. Also the compiler can do these micro optimizations much better than you. So don't try and confuse it. Just write code in the most readable way possible.

Don't use `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0])` it is so easy to break as array collapse into pointers at the drop of a hat. Use `std::size()` which works for arrays/containers but will fail to compile for pointers (which is what you want).

But if you switch to using `Iterator` based interface then you should use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

#### Style

Your bracing style is uncommon. But not so egregious that I would complain about. Normally brace style is defined by a local style guide. So if you are in a compnany or project just check that.

```
 // Most common C++ styles
 if ()
 {
     Statement;
 }

 // or
 if () {
     Statement;
 }
```

Comment: *"Don't use >> 1 to represent a divide by 2."* More importantly, don't use a right-shift to represent a divide with a *signed integer*, as the behavior is undefined. To make this work correctly, you need to cast the value to an unsigned integer. Then you could legally use a shift, but as you said, you should just do a division and let the compiler optimize it. (It will.)

Comment: While I agree that using an iterator interface like STL does is nicer, I wouldn't advocate using `template<typename I>` for a function that clearly only should accept only one specific type of iterator, namely `int *` in this case.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: What about `vector<int>` or `float[]` or `vector<float>` or `std::complex<int>[]` or `std::vector<std::complex<int>>` The interface is valid for all these types.

Comment: @LokiAstari: sure, but maybe that is not desired? In any case, the problem was not about making a template function, and the solution does not require a template function, so by suggesting it you risk adding confusion. You also did not provide an example of how to use your template function interface.

Comment: Isn't a misconception to have `int key` in the function signature? Since it's the value we are given, and trying to find the corresponding key.

Comment: @northerner You have to have the thing you are looking for. The point is to test for existence.

Comment: @MartinYork my point is shouldn't the parameter be called `value` - you aren't giving it the key, you are giving it the value.

Comment: @northerner You normally search something for the key. Searching for a value is always going to require a scan. It just happens in this situation the key and value are the same thing so I would not argue aginst either but normally you do a search for the key.

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid using `std::endl`

Use `"\n"` instead. It is guaranteed to produce the correct newline character(s) on all platforms.
The problem with `std::endl` is that it not only adds a newline, it also flushes the output stream. If you have a lot of data to write to the output, this can cause a significant slowdown.

So instead of:

```
std::cout << ar[i] << " is present" << std::endl;
```

Write the following:

```
std::cout << ar[i] << " is present\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `high` past end of the array, and replace

```
while ( low <= high )
```

with

```
while ( low != high )
```

you'll be able to search descending array by initial `low` > `high` values.

Comment: The iterator approach suggested by another answer provides the same benefit but is more idiomatic C++ than passing an array.